# handling multiple youtube videos

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have three youtube videos that I want to stop when the user click on a link link the page.
this is my code

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var youtubePlayer1;
    var youtubePlayer2;
    var youtubePlayer3;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        youtubePlayer1 = new YT.Player('firstPlayer', {

        });
        youtubePlayer2 = new YT.Player('secondPlayer', {

        });
        youtubePlayer3 = new YT.Player('thirdPlayer', {

        });
    }

    function stopVideo() {
        if (youtubePlayer1 != null) {
            youtubePlayer1.stopVideo();
        }
        if (youtubePlayer2 != null) {
            youtubePlayer2.stopVideo();
        }
        if (youtubePlayer3 != null) {
            youtubePlayer3.stopVideo();
        }
    }
```

This is the html code

```
<div id="blog">
                                    <!--///////////// UN ORDERED LIST /////////////-->
                                    <ul>
                                        <!--///////////// LIST /////////////-->
                                        <li>
                                            <!-- iframe -->
                                            <h3>
                                                <strong>להקת קולות - בהרקדה חסידית...</strong></h3>
                                            <br />
                                            <iframe id="firstPlayer" width="800" height="485" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/F0eR1KFkt58"
                                                style="border:0" ></iframe>
                                            <br />
                                            <br />
                                            <img src="images/bg3.PNG" alt="" /><p>
                                                <span>תאור הוידאו: </span>טקסט אודות הוידאו, תאריך</p>
                                        </li>
                                        <!--///////////// SECOND IMAGE /////////////-->
                                        <li>
                                            <!-- iframe -->
                                            <h3>
                                                <strong>להקת קולות - בהרקדה ישראלית מוטרפת...</strong></h3>
                                            <br />
                                            <iframe id="secondPlayer" width="800" height="485" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mPTX4guU1W8"
                                                style="border:0" ></iframe>
                                            <br />
                                            <br />
                                            <img src="images/bg3.PNG" alt="" /><p>
                                                <span>תאור הוידאו: </span>טקסט אודות הוידאו, תאריך</p>
                                        </li>
                                        <!--///////////// THIRD IMAGE /////////////-->
                                        <li>
                                            <!-- iframe -->
                                            <h3>
                                                <strong>להקת קולות - בואי בשלום...</strong></h3>
                                            <br />
                                            <iframe id="thirdPlayer" width="800" height="485" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/E-_ONZOcScU"
                                                style="border:0"></iframe>
                                            <br />
                                            <br />
                                            <img src="images/bg3.PNG" alt="" /><p>
                                                <span>תאור הוידאו: </span>טקסט אודות הוידאו, תאריך</p>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
```

when the user click on the link it calls the stopVideo function that cycle through all the players and stop them.

for some reason I can get it to work only on youtubePlayer2 object what am I doing wrong here?

Forgot to mention, when I debug the app using the chrome debugger I can see the the objects are defined and that the function is called.

Comment: Could you provide your html code as well?

Comment: Anybody can help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, its worked fine.

*Note* `http://` is missing in `src`, because **stackoverflow** shows an error while posting with src. so correct it and test.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
```

**Full working code**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
<div id="firstPlayer"></div>
<div id="secondPlayer"></div>
<div id="thirdPlayer"></div>
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var youtubePlayer1;
var youtubePlayer2;
var youtubePlayer3;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        youtubePlayer1 = new YT.Player('firstPlayer',{
            height: '240',
            width: '320',
            videoId: 'F0eR1KFkt58',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady1
            }
        });
        youtubePlayer2 = new YT.Player('secondPlayer', {
            height: '240',
            width: '320',
            videoId: 'mPTX4guU1W8',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady2
            }
        });
        youtubePlayer3 = new YT.Player('thirdPlayer', {
            height: '240',
            width: '320',
            videoId: 'E-_ONZOcScU',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady3
            }
        });
    }
function onPlayerReady1(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
        $('a').click(function(e) { 
            youtubePlayer1.stopVideo();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
function onPlayerReady2(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
        $('a').click(function(e) { 
            youtubePlayer2.stopVideo();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
function onPlayerReady3(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
        $('a').click(function(e) { 
            youtubePlayer3.stopVideo();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
</script>
    <a>Stop</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to do the trick, but is there a way to use this without letting those videos play all at once?

Comment: To disable auto start, you can remove `event.target.playVideo();` from `function onPlayerReady(event) {`

Comment: Also you have to note that, stop function will bind to all links(anchors)

Comment: Finally I have managed to get it to work, but it was pretty tricky and for design reasons I had issues with implementing this in my website. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think that in this way works:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLMF8/3/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2/swfobject.js"></script></head>

<body>

<div id="ytplayer1">
<p>You will need Flash 8 or better to view this content.</p>

</div>

<div id="ytplayer2">
<p>You will need Flash 8 or better to view this content.</p>

</div>

<div id="ytplayer3">
<p>You will need Flash 8 or better to view this content.</p>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };

swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/F0eR1KFkt58&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer1", "ytplayer1", "425", "365", "8", null, null, params);

swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/mPTX4guU1W8&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer2", "ytplayer2", "425", "365", "8", null, null, params);

swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/E-_ONZOcScU&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer3", "ytplayer3", "425", "365", "8", null, null, params);

function stop() {

  if (ytplayer1) {

    ytplayer1.stopVideo();

  }
  if (ytplayer2) {

    ytplayer2.stopVideo();

  }
  if (ytplayer3) {

    ytplayer3.stopVideo();

  }

}​

</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="stop();">Stop</a>


</body>

</html>​
```

Comment: I saw it working in the fiddle you sent but I can't get it to work on my local machine, running it with the visual studio  IIS express. should it run on local also?

Comment: It doesn't work very well, sometimes it's working and sometimes not

Answer (score 1):

This code sample should work without issue, and in my testing it worked without flaw. Try making sure the script tag is added at the bottom of the page.  This will help insure that the iframes are loaded by the time you make calls to them.  Also try out http://www.youtube.com/html5 to see if that has a more reliable experience.

Comment: I tried it on my local IIS express server and on jsfiddle, in my local IIS I can't even see the videos for some reason and on jsfiddle when I press the stop link the video is stopping but it's restarting after a second or two

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need for the if statement if your code just runs on when not being able to find the youtubeplayer, but I once solved a problem similar by adding a else statement that made sure something would happen - which may explain why the above was only happening every now and then.

It only takes a little copy and paste.

```
function stopVideo() {
    if (youtubePlayer1 != null) {
        youtubePlayer1.stopVideo();
    }
    else {
    youtubePlayer1.stopVideo(); 
    }
    if (youtubePlayer2 != null) {
        youtubePlayer2.stopVideo();
    }
    else {
    youtubePlayer2.stopVideo(); 
    }
    if (youtubePlayer3 != null) {
        youtubePlayer3.stopVideo();
    }
    else {
    youtubePlayer3.stopVideo(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it still doesn't seem to work. strange thing those youtube videos

Answer (score 0):

Mohamed Navas' answer (first answer) helped me to come up with this:

```
<br>
    <button id="pause">Pause</button>
<br>
<br>

<div id="firstPlayer"></div>
<div id="secondPlayer"></div>
<div id="thirdPlayer"></div>

<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var youtubePlayer1;
var youtubePlayer2;
var youtubePlayer3;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        youtubePlayer1 = new YT.Player('firstPlayer',{
            height: '240',
            width: '320',
            videoId: 'qV9HxRU4ozY',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });
        youtubePlayer2 = new YT.Player('secondPlayer', {
            height: '240',
            width: '320',
            videoId: 'nBRpWJ0QUH0',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });
        youtubePlayer3 = new YT.Player('thirdPlayer', {
            height: '240',
            width: '320',
            videoId: 'E-_ONZOcScU',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        document.getElementById('pause').onclick = function() {
            youtubePlayer1.pauseVideo();
            youtubePlayer2.pauseVideo();
            youtubePlayer3.pauseVideo();
            e.preventDefault();
        };
    };


</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tonhaoln/ancz2vkn/