# Multiple Youtube Iframe APIs

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

Can some please help me sort out why I can't have multiple Youtube API Iframes on the same page? When I try to copy and paste this code as another instance, one or the other does not appear. I have tried removing some of the first lines of this code, because I suspect that's where the problem lies, but I am relatively new at Javascript and I'm not sure what to do to proceed.

I need to install about 6 Youtube clips on my page and need to use the API so that I can use stopVideo() when the containing DIVs are hidden.

Help! Please! Forgive me if my code is ugly or calling unnecessary things. I have been throwing code at this for 24 hours trying to get it to work.

Each player is in it's own Absolute Div. Then a Youtube div is created using the Youtube API.

For Example, this is one instance...

```
<div id="notes1"  style="position:absolute; z-index:0; width:541px; left: 363px; top: 224px; height: auto; overflow:auto; overflow-x: hidden; background-color: #FFFFFF; layer-background-color: #FFFFFF; visibility: hidden;"> 

    <div id="notesplayer"></div>
   <script>

      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      var notesplayer;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        notesplayer = new YT.Player('notesplayer', {
          height: '365',
          width: '425',
          videoId: 'cmIg9MWhVss',
          playerVars: {
            modestbranding: 1,
            wmode: "opaque",
            autoplay:0,
        },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,

          }
        });
      }


      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        notesplayer.stopVideo();
      }


     function stop() {
  if (notesplayer) {
    notesplayer.stopVideo();
  }
     }
    </script>
</div>
```

And this is another instance...

```
<div id="married"  style="position:absolute; z-index:0; width:541px; left: 363px; top: 224px; height: auto; overflow:auto; overflow-x: hidden; background-color: #FFFFFF; layer-background-color: #FFFFFF; visibility: hidden;">
```

```
   <script>

      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      var marriedplayer;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        marriedplayer = new YT.Player('marriedplayer', {
          height: '365',
          width: '425',
          videoId: 'nREbUaxUlmE',
          playerVars: {
            modestbranding: 1,
            wmode: "opaque",
            autoplay:0,
        },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,

          }
        });
      }


      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        marriedplayer.stopVideo();
      }


     function stop() {
  if (marriedplayer) {
    marriedplayer.stopVideo();
  }
     }
    </script>
</div>
```

And ultimately I want to be able to control/stop each video within my existing show/hide Imagemap... for example....

```
<area shape="rect" coords="8,19,561,74" href="#" alt="Home" onmouseover="MM_showHideLayers('Film-Menu-Plain','','hide','Film-Menu-Married','','hide','Film-Menu-Run','','hide','Film-Menu-Notes1','','hide','Film-Menu-Notes2','','hide');notesplayer.stopVideo();marriedplayer.stopVideo();"/>
```

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you giving them all the same ID, 'notesplayer'? If so, that would explain why each

```
 new YT.Player('notesplayer', ...)
```

is overwriting the previous player object.

If not, please show some more code... so we can see how the html and javascript of each player relates to the others.

Comment: No, each instance I've been giving a new ID. 

For example

Comment: @user1965097: The example you gave in a comment didn't show up. Please edit your question to show more sample code.

Comment: Can't post code again for 5 hours, due to my reputation... but every embed is given their own id. In a new div, I have been changing every instance of the word 'notesplayer' to 'marriedplayer' or 'runningplayer' or whatever the ID is for each video. 

I saw a post that said I don't need to call onYouTubeIframeAPIReady again, once I've called it once on the page, but I'm not sure what that would do to the wording of new YT.Player script.

I will post more code tomorrow if nobody can help with what's here. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to what helped me with the same issue. [handling multiple youtube videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043799/handling-multiple-youtube-videos)

Where I got hung up was the same as you. We can't use multiple stacks of the youtube api script instead we've got to describe the variables together.

```
 <script>


var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    //call all your video ids' variables here
    var notesplayer;
    var marriedplayer;
    //then the function
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        notesplayer = new YT.Player('notesplayer', {
          height: '365',
          width: '425',
          videoId: 'cmIg9MWhVss',
          playerVars: {
            modestbranding: 1,
            wmode: "opaque",
            autoplay:0,
        },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,

          }
        });
        marriedplayer = new YT.Player('marriedplayer', {
          height: '365',
          width: '425',
          videoId: 'nREbUaxUlmE',
          playerVars: {
            modestbranding: 1,
            wmode: "opaque",
            autoplay:0,
        },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady2, //this can't be the same as the above one

          }
        });


      }
    // this ends that set and now you're ready to call some function events
    // notice how i refer to onPlayerReady2 for marriedplayer etc
    function onPlayerReady2(event) {
        marriedplayer.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script>


    var player1st;
    var player2nd;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { 
    player1st = new YT.Player('frame1st', {events: {'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}}); 
    player2nd = new YT.Player('frame2nd', {events: {'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}});
        }


    //function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player2nd = new YT.Player('frame2nd', {events: {'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}}); }


    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    alert(event.target.getPlayerState());

    }

</script>






<iframe id="frame1st" style="position: relative; height: 220px; width: 400px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1g30Xyh6Wqc?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"></iframe><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player1st.playVideo(); return false">play1st</a><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player1st.pauseVideo(); return false">pause1st</a><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player1st.stopVideo(); return false">stop1st</a>




<iframe id="frame2nd" style="position: relative; height: 220px; width: 400px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/T39hYJAwR40?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"></iframe><br>

<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player2nd.playVideo(); return false">play2nd</a><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player2nd.pauseVideo(); return false">pause2nd</a><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player2nd.stopVideo(); return false">stop2nd</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sumanP/rzeb23aq/1/